# jaspersoft studio 6.11.0 pie chart percentage values problem

Tags: jasper-reports, pie-chart, percentage

I was creating report with pie chart in jasper studio, while i got problem. I need to get shown percentage value. [This article](http://www.rajeshsirsikar.com/custom-formatting-of-data-labels-of-a-pie-chart/) was helpful but pie chart only changes in 'design' view like this:
**pic 1**.

When i change like in link above: **pic2**.

Nothing happens in 'preview' view, even if i download it as PDF: **pic3**.

I think I just need to configure it somehow bot i have no idea how and I couldn't find any answer on Google.

**pic1:**

[image: pic1]

**pic2:**

[image: pic2]

**pic3:**

[image: pic3]

Comment: please share the jrxml file

Comment: sure, https://www68.zippyshare.com/v/hyJKI84k/file.html

Answer (score 1):

I had  a similar problem. The pie labels would always show the LABEL no matter what I set on the field "Label Format", even though the "Legend Label Format" would be working allright.

So the problem was, when adding the Pie Chart from the palette with drag and drop, it would give you a Wizard window, where you can configure the pie. And there you set the Label for the Pie.

This value would not show on the Pie Chart "Chart Plot" (field "Label Format" was always empty or with whatever value I set), but the value on Pie Chart Wizard was always the Label value. The Wizard value was overriding the value on the properties.

To fix it, just open the wizard with Right Click on the chart and remove the label (red square on the image attached) and then it would apply correctly the value on the properties pane.

[image: Pie Chart Wizard - Label]